# Using the function SUM?

Tags: sql, sum

I have this query:

```
Select t1.col5,
       t1.col6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'A' THEN t2.col2 ELSE 0
                WHEN t2.col1 = 'B' THEN t2.col2 * -1 ELSE 0
       END) AS price,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'C' THEN t2.col2 + 100  ELSE 0
       END) AS bonus
       FROM t1, t2
       WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col4
       AND (price + bonus ) <> 0
      GROUP BY  t1.col5,
                t1.col6
```

But I can't do `(price + bonus ) <> 0`? I have this message: price invalid identifier!
How can I do to use the names of my SUM in a WHERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use column aliases (or, for that matter, aggregates) in the `WHERE` clause. So what you want to do is use a subquery OR put the aggregates in a `HAVING` clause. I'll show the subquery below, which I think is easier since you don't have to reproduce all the keystrokes (you need to use the aggregates themselves, and not their aliases, in a `HAVING` clause):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    Select t1.col5,
           t1.col6,
           SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'A' THEN t2.col2 ELSE 0
               WHEN t2.col1 = 'B' THEN t2.col2 * -1 ELSE 0
           END) AS price,
           SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'C' THEN t2.col2 + 100  ELSE 0
           END) AS bonus
       FROM t1, t2
      WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col4
      GROUP BY  t1.col5,
            t1.col6
) WHERE (price + bonus ) <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Constraining on aggregate functions needs to be done in a `HAVING` clause:

```
Select t1.col5,
       t1.col6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'A' THEN t2.col2 ELSE 0
                WHEN t2.col1 = 'B' THEN t2.col2 * -1 ELSE 0
       END) AS price,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'C' THEN t2.col2 + 100  ELSE 0
       END) AS bonus
       FROM t1, t2
       WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col4

      GROUP BY  t1.col5,
                t1.col6
    having SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'A' THEN t2.col2 ELSE 0
                WHEN t2.col1 = 'B' THEN t2.col2 * -1 ELSE 0
       END) + SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'C' THEN t2.col2 + 100  ELSE 0
       END) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that alias - check out the order of operations in a sql query: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

You need to try something like this:

```
Select t1.col5,
       t1.col6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'A' THEN t2.col2 ELSE 0
                WHEN t2.col1 = 'B' THEN t2.col2 * -1 ELSE 0
       END) AS price,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'C' THEN t2.col2 + 100  ELSE 0
       END) AS bonus
       FROM t1, t2
       WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col4
       AND (SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'A' THEN t2.col2 ELSE 0 WHEN t2.col1 = 'B' THEN t2.col2 * -1 ELSE 0 END)
            +
           SUM(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 'C' THEN t2.col2 + 100  ELSE 0 END)) <> 0
          GROUP BY  t1.col5,
                    t1.col6
```

Comment: The aggregates need to go into a `HAVING` clause - they can't be in the `WHERE` clause.